# Recognising an image from a training set, JavaCV

Tags: opencv, set, javacv

so basically Im doing a project on image recognition, and I'm trying to use a recogniser to identify a person, the quirk comes when i need that recogniser to use a different training set for each folder i scan for an image.

The code for iteration through folders is as follows:

```
public class FileIterator {
int ft; int et; int at;
OpenCVFaceRecognizer recogniser;
public FileIterator(int ft, int et, int at){
    this.ft=ft;
    this.et=et;
    this.at=at;
}

public void main() {
    OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
File[] files = new File("C:/Users/David/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Honours Project/storage").listFiles();

JOptionPane jP=new JOptionPane();
jP.showMessageDialog(jP, "Please look at the camera");

   try{
        grabber.start();
             System.out.println("Grabbing");
      try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        IplImage img = grabber.grab();
        if (img != null) {
           try{
            BufferedImage img1 =img.getBufferedImage();
             File image = new File("recognize.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(img1, "jpg", image);
                System.out.println("Image written");
           }
             catch(Exception x){
                 x.printStackTrace();
             }
             grabber.stop();

        }

         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
showFiles(files);
}

public void showFiles(File[] files) {
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("\n---- Directory: " + file.getName()+" ----");
        // showFiles(file.listFiles());
        recogniser = new OpenCVFaceRecognizer ("storage/"+file.getName(),"recognize.jpg",ft,et,at);           
    } else {
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
    }
}
}
}
```

So, the recogniser class takes a training directory and an image to compare to as parameters (the rest are settings for thresholds). I feed it a directory with every loop and keep the image to recognise the same.

Right now the recogniser recognises the person it has been trained for no matter what, ie even if the person in the file is different from the person in the picture, they will still be recognised and let through. Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

ps,(if you need the code for the recogniser class let me know).